# Need SQL to Get Max of row based on my specific column while joining

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have sample Oracle query and its respective output

```
select t1.account,t1.ID ,t2.NAME , t2.CHILDAC from t1,t2 where t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

**Output Example**

```
ACCOUNT       ID        NAME    CHILDAC
9001          1         xxx      root1
9006          3         xxy      root1
9003          4         xra      root1
9008          5         xii      root2
9011          6         xxt      root2
9045          7         xxy      root3
9089          8         xxu      root3
9033          10        xss      root4
```

My expected output is given below,which means I need to return the row of unique value of **CHILDAC** column with max of **ID** column

**Expected out**

```
ACCOUNT       ID        NAME    CHILDAC
9003          4         xra      root1
9011          6         xxt      root2
9089          8         xxu      root3
9033          10        xss      root4
```

Please provide me SQL for the above mentioned scenoria

Comment: Why do have `mysql` and `sql-server` tags if you need a query for Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` with a subquery for this:

```
select *
from (
    select t1.account, t1.ID, t2.NAME, t2.CHILDAC, 
           row_number() over (partition by t2.Childac order by t1.id desc) rn
    from t1 
        join t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
) t
where rn = 1
```

- [Condensed Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6a13/4)